# iPhone - how to determine carrier of the device (AT&T, Verizon, etc?)

Tags: iphone, ios, core-telephony, carrier

Is there a way to get information about the carrier of iPhones programmatically?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1st Import `#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>` as well as `#import <CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>`
(make sure you have the CoreTelephone.framework installed too).

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *phoneInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier *phoneCarrier = [phoneInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
NSLog(@"Carrier = %@", [phoneCarrier carrierName]);
[phoneInfo release];
```

Comment: Notice that this tells you only the original SIM carrier, not current one in case of roaming.

Comment: this is not working anymore, just returning "Carrier" for me.

Answer (score 6):

Heres the Swift version:

```
import CoreTelephony

let phoneInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
let phoneCarrier = phoneInfo.subscriberCellularProvider
print(phoneCarrier?.carrierName)
```

Answer (score 0):

While developing in Swift 3.0, You just need to import CoreTelephony in you link binary with libraries in Build phases.

// Setup the Network Info and create a CTCarrier object

```
 let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
 let carrier = networkInfo.subscriberCellularProvider
```

// Get carrier name

```
 print(carrier?.carrierName)
```

That's it.