# iPhone - Detecting SIM card availability

Tags: iphone, ios, core-telephony

I am using the answer in this topic. [iPhone - how to determine carrier of the device (AT&T, Verizon, etc?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161235/iphone-how-to-determine-carrier-of-the-device-att-verizon-etc/8161253#8161253) which is the same as [getting operator details in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204121/getting-operator-details-in-iphone). Although it works fine when using a sim card, the returned carrier name if there is no SIM card is the old carrier name. It doesn't detect that the SIM is removed.

I know this contradicts with Apple documentation that if there is no carrier, CTCarrier object shall be nil. But in my app I logged the carrier info and it gives me the latest carrier name although no sim is installed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009596-CH1-SW1) for `[CTCarrier carrierName]`:

> If you configure a device for a carrier and then remove the SIM card,
>   this property retains the name of the carrier.

As far as I know, you cannot detect if the SIM card is installed. You can only determine if a WWAN connection is available using [`Reachability`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: This helped but didn't solve the problem. WWAN connection may not exist, but SIM card may be still inserted (if the user switches off the data and 3G).

Comment: Right, and there is no way to check if the SIM card is present.

Comment: In the same documentation link you provided, can't `mobileCountryCode` or `mobileNetworkCode` be used to detect if SIM is present or not? The documentation states that those values will be `nil` if there is no SIM present. It doesn't seem that those properties are retained

Comment: @wnafee Unfortunately, that is not always the case, as the values are retained unless the device is restarted after removing the SIM card. However, YMMV with different iOS versions.

Answer (score 9):

```
@import CoreTelephony;

-(BOOL)hasCellularCoverage
{
    CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new];
    CTCarrier *carrier = [networkInfo subscriberCellularProvider];


    if (!carrier.isoCountryCode) {
        NSLog(@"No sim present Or No cellular coverage or phone is on airplane mode.");
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The [CTCarrier](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/Reference/Reference.html) object has 5 properties:

```
allowsVOIP
carrierName
isoCountryCode
mobileCountryCode
mobileNetworkCode
```

I have made some tests regarding CTCarrier and I have come to the conclusion that for iOS 7 **only carrierName and allowsVOIP are retained** when SIM is removed. isoCountryCode, mobileCountryCode and mobileNetworkCode are reset for iOS 7. That's how you can detect if a SIM is present or not.

For iOS 6 all the values are retained.

I performed the tests using an iPhone 4S and iPhone 5 both running iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

Swift version:

```
func hasCellularCoverage() -> Bool {

    let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()

    guard let info = networkInfo.subscriberCellularProvider else {return false}

    if let carrier = info.isoCountryCode {
        print("No sim present Or No cellular coverage or phone is on airplane mode. Carrier = \(carrier)");
        return false
    }

    return true

}
```

or

```
func hasCellularCoverage() -> Bool {

    let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()

    guard let info = networkInfo.subscriberCellularProvider else {return false}

    return info.isoCountryCode != nil ? false : true

}
```

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps：

```
    if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
        return CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().serviceSubscriberCellularProviders?.first?.value.mobileNetworkCode != nil
    } else {
        if let _ = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().subscriberCellularProvider?.isoCountryCode {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remember to add "import CoreTelephony"

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.4 answer**

Accepted answer is outdated or incorrect.

```
protocol SimCardServiceProtocol {
    var isAvailableSIM: Bool { get }
}

final class SimCardService: SimCardServiceProtocol {

    var isAvailableSIM: Bool {
        return CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().serviceSubscriberCellularProviders?.first?.value.mobileNetworkCode != nil
    }
}
```