# MobileCOuntryCode iOS not working

Tags: ios, mobile-country-code

From the below post i am trying to detect the **SIM** in iPhone

[Detect if Sim Card is available in iPhone programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644502/detect-if-sim-card-is-available-in-iphone-programmatically?rq=1)

I tried the same code provided by you but it always return me (null). I have added `core telephony framework` and imported `CTCarrier.h` file. Is there anything more i need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>

CTTelephonyNetworkInfo* info = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier* _carrier = info.subscriberCellularProvider;
NSLog(@"carrierName %@",_carrier.carrierName);
NSLog(@"isoCountryCode %@",_carrier.isoCountryCode);
NSLog(@"mobileCountryCode %@",_carrier.mobileCountryCode);
NSLog(@"mobileNetworkCode %@",_carrier.mobileNetworkCode);
```

Try this method its work.

Comment: it returns null every time when I use iPod Touch may be because its not sim based. But in iPhone it returns 404.

Comment: Same here.. its returning 404 even in my iPhone.. any idea on how to proceed further?

Comment: Now Apple has deprecated this API and hasn't provided a new API. Typical apple