# iOS dual sim card, default sim card for cellular data

Tags: ios, iphone, ios12, dual-sim

there is a Dual SIM support for iPhone XS, iPhone XS Max, and iPhone XR. In my app, can I know that which sim card is selected for the default cellular data? Is there any iOS 12 api can do that?

Comment: Check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488898/iphone-detecting-sim-card-availability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488898/iphone-detecting-sim-card-availability)