# iOS: Detect if device has a SIM card

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I would like to detect if the user has a SIM in their device.

There are similar questions (for example: [iPhone - Detecting SIM card availability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488898/iphone-detecting-sim-card-availability)), but the suggested solutions rely on the Core Telephony framework which is now mostly deprecated.

I thought `canSendText` of `MFMessageComposeViewController` might work, but it also returns `true` for devices without SIM card. Probably because the user doesn't need a SIM card to use iMessage?

Does anyone know of other possibilities?

Comment: What about [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/cttelephonynetworkinfo). Part of CoreTelephony but not deprecated.

Comment: @PtitXav The class is not deprecated, but its property serviceSubscriberCellularProviders is.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to detect SIM card available on device without `CoreTelephony` then use the `CTCarrier` class from the `CoreTelephony` framework, but without importing the entire framework:

```
func isSIMCardAvailable() -> Bool {
     guard let info = CTCarrier() else {
         return false
     }
     return !info.isoCountryCode.isEmpty
}
```

Comment: CTCarrier is deprecated: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/ctcarrier